# How to remove items with something common from list in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

**code**
I am trying to remove cards with the same color and number from total cards but I am having trouble making conditions for my for loop

```
total_Cards=['Ace_of_clubs', '2_of_clubs', '3_of_clubs', '4_of_clubs', '5_of_clubs', '6_of_clubs', '7_of_clubs', '8_of_clubs', '9_of_clubs', '10_of_clubs', 'King_of_clubs', 'Queen_of_clubs', 'Jack_of_clubs', 'Ace_of_diamonds', '2_of_diamonds', '3_of_diamonds', '4_of_diamonds', '5_of_diamonds', '6_of_diamonds', '7_of_diamonds', '8_of_diamonds', '9_of_diamonds', '10_of_diamonds', 'King_of_diamonds', 'Queen_of_diamonds', 'Jack_of_diamonds', 'Ace_of_spades', '2_of_spades', '3_of_spades', '4_of_spades', '5_of_spades', '6_of_spades', '7_of_spades', '8_of_spades', '9_of_spades', '10_of_spades', 'King_of_spades', 'Queen_of_spades', 'Jack_of_spades', 'Jocker', 'Ace_of_hearts', '2_of_hearts', '3_of_hearts', '4_of_hearts', '5_of_hearts', '6_of_hearts', '7_of_hearts', '8_of_hearts', '9_of_hearts', '10_of_hearts', 'King_of_hearts', 'Queen_of_hearts', 'Jack_of_hearts']
for i in range(len(total_Cards)):
    first=total_Cards[i].split("_")
    for y in range(len(total_Cards)-1):
        y+=1
        second=total_Cards[y].split("_")
        if second[0]==['jocker']:
            pass
        elif first[0]==["jocker"]:
            pass
        elif ((first[0]==second[0])and((first[2]==("spades")or(first[2]=="clubs"))and (second[2]==("spades")or(second[2]=="clubs")))):
            total_Cards.pop(i)
            total_Cards.pop(y)
        elif ((first[0]==second[0])and((first[2]==("diamonds")or(first[2]=="hearts"))and (second[2]==("diamonds")or(second[2]=="hearts")))):
            total_Cards.pop(i)
            total_Cards.pop(y)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of ```first[0]``` and ```second[0]```?  What do you get? How does it differ from the value you are comparing it with in your ```if``` and ```elif``` statements?

Comment: What should be the final result?

Comment: If you have a full deck of 52 cards (plus Jokers), you should have nothing in the output, since each diamond number has its hearts counterpart, and same for clubs and spades. Therefore, if you want what I understand you want, your `total_Cards` list would return with only two jokers.

Comment: itprorh66: what I am trying to do is I am trying to find cards with the same number and same color; first[0]should be equal to the first value of cards or the card number for eg: "ace_of hearts "equal to ace as first[0] and the "2_of_hearts" gives 2 in the first[0] I get value as ace and second[0] gives 2 now if they both are same the statement then check if the last value or first[2] and seconf[2] is of the same color or ("spades", "clubs") if yes then the code removes them both if not then code checks next index of the  string if any of them is jocker then code leaves the index and pick next

Comment: Andrej Kesely: the final result should be a joker since every card has the same color and number pair

Comment: MatBBastos: you are partially correct the result should be 1 jocker I had already explained why is that in the above two comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since there are some things about your question that are not very clear, I am going to assume what seems reasonable and answer with that in mind. My assumptions are:

1. When there is a match of number and color, both cards should be removed;
2. If there are repeated cards (same color **and** number), all of their instances should be removed.

So, first, I believe in order to make the comparisons easier to understand and more efficient, we can make a specific function to tell us the color of the card based on its suit. This will make your conditions much cleaner:

```py
def get_suit_color(suit: str) -> str:
    if suit.lower() == "clubs" or suit.lower() == "spades":
        return "black"
    elif suit.lower() == "diamonds" or suit.lower() == "hearts":
        return "red"
    else:
        raise ValueError("Suit is not a supported type (clubs, spades, diamonds, hearts)")
```

This function simplifies the color comparison, as we can see from an example:

```py
foo = 'Clubs'
bar = 'sPADES'
baz = 'diAmOnDs'
qux = 'HEARTS'

print(get_suit_color(foo))
print(get_suit_color(bar))
print(get_suit_color(baz))
print(get_suit_color(qux))
```

That will output:

```sh
>>> black
>>> black
>>> red
>>> red
```

So, now, let's get into removing 'color duplicates'. The function, basically, gets the number and suit of a card and compares to the pair of number and suit of each *other* card. If the numbers match, we check color, if the color then matches, we remove the card from the list we will return. This will work:

```py
def deduplicate(cards_list: list[str]) -> list:
    return_list = cards_list.copy()
    for card in cards_list:
        new_list = cards_list.copy()
        try:
            number, _, suit = card.split("_")
        except ValueError:
            # Happens when Joker is found
            continue
        else:
            new_list.remove(card)
            for other_card in new_list:
                try:
                    other_number, _, other_suit = other_card.split("_")
                    # print(f"Comparing {number} of {suit} with {other_number} of {other_suit}")
                except ValueError:
                    # Happens when Joker is found
                    continue
                else:
                    if not number == other_number:
                        continue
                    else:
                        if get_suit_color(suit) == get_suit_color(other_suit):
                            try:
                                return_list.remove(other_card)
                            except ValueError:
                                # Happens when there are repeated cards (same number and suit)
                                continue
                            # print(f"Updated list:\n{return_list}")
    return return_list
```

Note that the `get_suit_color` function is used to compare the two cards (`card` and `other_card`). I left two commented `print` statements because I believe they might aid in the understanding of the function, though they pollute the output.
Another important thing is copying the original list, not to change it. The `return_list` starts off just like `cards_list`, and at each match of color and number, cards are removed. The `new_list` is just an object created by removing the current card of the list, in order to avoid comparing it with itself.

With both these functions, you can expect this to go well:

```py
all_cards = ['Ace_of_clubs', '2_of_clubs', '3_of_clubs', '4_of_clubs', '5_of_clubs', '6_of_clubs', '7_of_clubs', '8_of_clubs', '9_of_clubs', '10_of_clubs', 'King_of_clubs', 'Queen_of_clubs', 'Jack_of_clubs', 'Ace_of_diamonds', '2_of_diamonds', '3_of_diamonds', '4_of_diamonds', '5_of_diamonds', '6_of_diamonds', '7_of_diamonds', '8_of_diamonds', '9_of_diamonds', '10_of_diamonds', 'King_of_diamonds', 'Queen_of_diamonds', 'Jack_of_diamonds', 'Ace_of_spades', '2_of_spades', '3_of_spades', '4_of_spades', '5_of_spades', '6_of_spades', '7_of_spades', '8_of_spades', '9_of_spades', '10_of_spades', 'King_of_spades', 'Queen_of_spades', 'Jack_of_spades', 'Joker', 'Ace_of_hearts', '2_of_hearts', '4_of_hearts', '5_of_hearts', '6_of_hearts', '7_of_hearts', '8_of_hearts', '9_of_hearts', '10_of_hearts', 'King_of_hearts', 'Queen_of_hearts', 'Jack_of_hearts']

new_deck = deduplicate(all_cards)
print(new_deck)
```

The output should be:

```sh
>>> ['3_of_diamonds', 'Joker']
```

Since I removed the 3 of Hearts from `all_cards`, and there is only one Joker.

---

Note: if you have older Python, remove the type annotations from the functions. Also, I believe "Joker" is the correct spelling, so I used that.

Comment: Hey buddy! thank you so much! I didn't expect that the solution will be this much fast and detailed. I am a beginner I just learned python and working on a terminal game of cards and yes sorry for the bad explanation and wrong spelling. I am still a 15-year-old  ^_^  THANK YOU ;-)

Comment: @AshmitGarg No problem, just take those things into account when visiting Stack Overflow again. People are willing to help, but they need to have room for it. Going through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and details of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should cover the basics! ;P

Comment: Also, if my assumptions are correct and this solves the question, please mark it as the accepted answer.